# Can I use log.IsDebugEnabled before a log.Trace?

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using log4net to log messages from my c# application. I want to know if I can use the following code when logging a trace entry:

```
if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
     log.Trace("MY trace entry");
```

I am working on the assumption that if the logging level is set to trace then the debug will always be enabled. As Debug and trace will only be used for troubleshooting, it would be permissible for any debug code to also enter this block.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need that if statement? I ask because the log level setting will already control what log calls are actually allowed through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible to use something like a LevelRangeFilter to disable logging at the debug level but leave it enable at the traceLevel, which might cause problems with your method

So why not check for the actual level?

eg

```
if (log.Logger.IsEnabledFor(log4net.Core.Level.Trace))
    log.Trace("MY trace entry");
```

Comment: I didn't know that was possible, all the examples I have found use  log.IsDebugEnabled. Thanks!